# jQuery doesn't change Css of tags or maybe can't find the tags

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have the code below which I use `clone()` and `delegate()`. 
The code is being load in a jQuery UI dialog with a link. 
the problem is Ajax being triggered properly, and it calls to success methods as it supposed but none of Ok or noOk divs are being shown, I mean the alerts trigger but the css of divs don't change, Where do you think my problem is? is there something wrong with selectors? thanks

```
    <input id="TaskId" name="TaskId" type="hidden" value="18" />
    <div id="MainDiv">
        <div id="toClone">
            <div style="display: inline;">
                <select id="Tasksess">
                    <option value="">لطفاً کار را انتخاب کنيد</option>
                    <optgroup label="کار های جديد">
                            <option value="16"style="">q3fe</option>
                            <option value="18"style="">fjhv j</option>
                            <option value="19"style="">wref</option>
                            <option value="25"style="">ff</option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="کار های در دست اقدام">
                            <option value="13"style="">rr</option>
                            <option value="15"style="">yy</option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="کار های تمام شده">
                            <option value="14"style="">tt</option>
                            <option value="18"style="">fjhv j</option>
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline;">
                <select id="Statusess" name="Statusess">
                    <option value="">لطفاً وابستگی را انتخاب کنيد</option>
                    <option value="1">پيشنياز</option>
                    <option value="2">همنياز</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;" id="Ok">
                ok
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;" id="noOk">
                تکراری
            </div>
            <div id="loadingGif" style="display: none;">
                <img src="/Content/Images/ajax-loader/253L.gif" alt=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var Maindiv = $("#MainDiv");
            var toClone = $("#toClone");

            //$("#Statusess").each(function () {
                $("#MainDiv").delegate('#Statusess', 'change', function () {
                    if ($(this).find(":selected").val() != "") {                    
                        if ($(this).parent().prev().find(":selected").val() != "") {
                            $(this).parent().parent().find("#loadingGif").attr("style", "display: inline;");
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '/ProjectAdmin/Project/AddTaskDependency?MainTaskId=' + $("#TaskId").val() + '&DependentTaskId=' + $(this).parent().prev().find(":selected").val() + '&Status=' + $(this).find(":selected").val(),
                                type: 'GET',
                                success: function (data, status) {
                                    if (data != "0") {
                                        $(this).parent().parent().find("#Ok").css('display', 'inline');
                                        $(this).parent().parent().find("#noOk").css('display', 'none');
  alert("1");
                                    }
                                    else if (data == "0") {
                                        $(this).parent().parent().find("#Ok").css('display', 'none');
                                        $(this).parent().parent().find("#noOk").css('display', 'inline');
  alert("2");
                                    }
                                    var div = $('div:eq(0)', Maindiv).clone();
                                    Maindiv.append(div);
                                }
                            });
                            $(this).parent().parent().find("#loadingGif").attr("style", "display: none;");

                        }
                    }
                });
            //});

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: An element's ID should be unique on the page, so you don't really need                                         `$(this).parent().parent().find("#Ok");`. `$("#Ok")` should be fine.

Comment: Your use of $(this).parent().parent() is very confusing as the DOM doesn't reflect your selections... whilst it is ok JQuery what is it selecting? $(this) = "#MainDiv", therefore .parent().parent() would select its parents parent... that isn't what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your main problem is in your selectors, yes. You can add extra alerts to spit out values at each reference to see where it goes wrong.

I got irritated with that method so I made some changes to your setup and (aside from the ajax piece that I can't test without having your AskTaskDependancy file) got it working I believe as you expected.

First off, [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6qLL/)

Note: I changed all the text to english. This has no bearing on your code, I'm just illiterate in not-english, so feel free to change it back as it has no effect on the code.

**The change log**

- Added error `alert()`s if a `select`'s value is empty
- `$(this).find(":selected").val()` to simply `$(this).val()`
- several of the reference names to camelCase
- all IDs inside the MainDiv to classes
- moved class name from the select elements to the div holding each
- `.parent.prev()` to `.parent.children(".tasksess")` (and similar reference scheme for other elements)
- set a var for easy reference to each div/select
- changed css() to attr() (for hiding/showing ok/notOk)
- I built the ajax url on separate lines for easier reading.
- Moved the `clone()` outside of the ajax request to verify that it works (feel free to move it back as needed - be aware the loadingGif which remains shown in each copy if you don't hide it first)
- commented out the ajax request for testing

**The new HTML**

```
<input id="TaskId" name="TaskId" type="hidden" value="18" />
<div id="MainDiv">
    <div class="toClone">
        <div class="tasksess" style="display: inline;">
            <select name="tasksess">
                <option value="">Select a Task</option>
                <optgroup label="Group 1">
                        <option value="16"style="">q3fe</option>
                        <option value="18"style="">fjhv j</option>
                        <option value="19"style="">wref</option>
                        <option value="25"style="">ff</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Group 2">
                        <option value="13"style="">rr</option>
                        <option value="15"style="">yy</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Group 3">
                        <option value="14"style="">tt</option>
                        <option value="18"style="">fjhv j</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="statusess" style="display: inline;">
            <select name="statusess">
                <option value="">Select a Status</option>
                <option value="1">opt8</option>
                <option value="2">opt9</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="ok" style="display: none;">
            Everything looks good!
        </div>
        <div class="notOk" style="display: none;">
            Something went wrong!
        </div>
        <div class="loadingGif" style="display: none;">
            Loading...
            <img src="/Content/Images/ajax-loader/253L.gif" alt=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**The new jQuery/JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var Maindiv = $("#MainDiv");
    var toClone = $(".toClone");

    $("#MainDiv").delegate('.statusess', 'change', function () {
        var thisSel = $(this).children("select");
        var prevSel = $(this).parent().children(".tasksess").children("select");
        var divOk = $(this).parent().children(".ok");
        var divNotOk = $(this).parent().children(".notOk");
        var divLoad = $(this).parent().children(".loadingGif");

        if (thisSel.val() != "") {
            console.log("status changed to val " + thisSel.val());
            if (prevSel.val() != "") {
                console.log("task is val "+prevSel.val());

                divLoad.attr("style", "display: inline;");
                var url = '/ProjectAdmin/Project/AddTaskDependency';
                url += '?MainTaskId=' + $("#TaskId").val();
                url += '&DependentTaskId=' + prevSel.val();
                url += '&Status=' + thisSel.val();
                console.log("URL= "+url);
                /*
                $.ajax({
                    url: url, type: 'GET',
                    success: function (data, status) {
                        if (data != "0") {
                            divOk.attr("style","display:inline;");
                            divNotOk.attr("style","display:none;");
                        }
                        else if (data == "0") {
                            divOk.attr("style","display:none;");
                            divNotOk.attr("style","display:inline;");
                        }
                    }
                });
                */
                divLoad.attr("style", "display: none;");
                var div = $('div:eq(0)', Maindiv).clone();
                Maindiv.append(div);

            } else { alert("Select 1 val is empty"); }
        } else { alert("Select 2 val is empty"); }
    });

});​
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say for sure this is the issue, but it is certainly something you should correct. If I understand your code correctly, you are cloning the `#toClone` div. However, within that div are numerous children with id's, including your `#Ok` and `#noOk`. *Id's are supposed to be **unique** to a page*, so once you clone, you no longer have unique items. Therefore, you should change them all to classes:

- `id="toClone"` to `class="toClone"`
- `id="Tasksess"` to `class="Tasksess"`
- `id="Statusess"` to `class="Statusess"`
- `id="Ok"` to `class="Ok"`
- `id="noOk"` to `class="noOk"`
- `id="loadingGif"` to `class="loadingGif"`

(I do question, however, if you actually want `Ok`, `noOk`, and `loadingGif` to be children of the `toClone` div, or if you just want them to be unique children of the `MainDiv`. Your code seems so. If the latter, then you need to change your closing `</div>` tag for your `toClone` div to not be wrapping the unique `Ok`, `noOk`, and `loadingGif` elements. In such a case, you could leave the id's for those unique children.)

Once changed, you will need to change the rest of your code to select for classes, not ids; but also for the specific classes that are children of the new clone. Changing to classes may resolve your issue, because the multiple id items created by the clone could be making it so your jquery is not finding the items.

Answer (score 0):

The following line is incorrect:

```
$$("#MainDiv").delegate('#Statusess', 'change', function () {
```

Change `$$("#MainDiv")` to `$("#MainDiv")`.

Comment: sorry, that was a copy paste problem, in my code that's correct